# How to not delete an already existing SQLite database during a patch update

Tags: android

I have installed my Android application with a blank database during the initial stage. The installation will then create a database with the name Inventory and copy the database already created with different tables using SQLite browser into the newly created database. After some days data will be stored in the SQLite database while running my application.

The problem is that when I'm installing the application for a patch update with some modification for the next release. My already running application database needs to stay there. What can I do to retain the old database while installing with new apk file?

Also what if I need to update the database during the patch update without losing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are maualy adding the database onto the Android storage, so it can't be retained in the project.
You should build a database from the project and insert data within, to the database is generated when first execution is initiated.

Here is a great tutorial for that: [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

And another one: [androidforbeginners.blogspot.com](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-multiple-sqlite-database.html)

I hope that helps

Comment: with this method the data will lose.I need my already entered data there itself

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the database already exists by calling `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(String, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int)`. If it throws a `SQLiteException` it does not exist and only then should you copy your database file.

I suggest you extend the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and implement the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` and `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)` methods to help manage your database creation and upgrades.